# Trying to find values within excel cell based on given pairs in R df

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, matrix

I am using this excel sheet that I have currently read into R: https://www.knomad.org/sites/default/files/2018-04/bilateralmigrationmatrix20170_Apr2018.xlsx

```
dput(head(remittance, 5))
```

The output is:

```
structure(list(`Remittance-receiving country (across)                                                              -                                                 Remittance-sending country (down)` = c("Australia", 
"Brazil", "Canada"), Brazil = c("27.868809286999106", "0", "31.284184411144214"
), Canada = c("46.827693406219382", "1.5806325278762619", "0"
), `Czech Republic` = c("104.79905129342241", "3.0488843262423089", 
"176.79676736179096"), Finland = c("26.823089572300752", "1.3451674211686246", 
"37.781150857376964"), France = c("424.37048861305249", "123.9763417712491", 
"1296.7352242506483"), Germany = c("556.4140279523856", "66.518143815367239", 
"809.9621650533453"), Hungary = c("200.08597014449356", "11.953328254521287", 
"436.0811601171776"), Indonesia = c("172.0021287331823", "1.3701340430259537", 
"33.545925908780198"), Italy = c("733.51652291459231", "116.74264895322995", 
"1072.1119887588022"), `Korea, Rep.` = c("259.97044386689589", 
"20.467939414361016", "326.94157937864327"), Netherlands = c("133.48932759488602", 
"4.7378343766684532", "181.28828076733771"), Philippines = c("1002.3593555086774", 
"1.5863355979877207", "2369.5223195675494"), Poland = c("109.73486651698796", 
"5.8313637459523129", "341.10408952685464"), `Russian Federation` = c("19.082541158574934", 
"1.0136604494838692", "58.760989426089431"), `Saudi Arabia` = c("13.578431465294949", 
"0.32506772760873404", "15.511213677040857"), Sweden = c("91.887827513176489", 
"5.1132733094740352", "65.860232580192786"), Thailand = c("383.08245004577498", 
"2.7410805494977684", "79.370683058792849"), `United Kingdom` = c("1084.0742194994727", 
"4.2050614573174592", "568.62605950140266"), `United States` = c("188.06242727403128", 
"49.814372612310521", "661.98049661387927"), WORLD = c("5578.0296723604206", 
"422.37127035334271", "8563.264510816849")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I currently have a dataframe of two columns "Source" and "Destination" where each row is a pair of countries which I created by doing:

```
countries = c("Australia","Brazil", "Canada", "Czech Republic", "Germany", "Finland", "United Kingdom", "Italy", "Poland", "Russian Federation", "Sweden", "United States", "Philippines", "France", "Netherlands", "Hungary", "Saudi Arabia", "Thailand", "Korea, Rep.", "Indonesia")


pairs = t(combn(countries, 2))
```

I would like to use each pair to extract its corresponding value from the excel sheet above. (In the Excel sheet "Source" is the first column of countries-down and "Destination is the first row countries-across)

For example a sample of the df that I have looks as follows (it currently contains 190 pairs):

```
pairs = data.frame(Source = c("Australia", "Australia", "Australia"), Destination = c("Brazil", "Canada", "Czech Republic"))
```

Where the first pair in my df is (Australia, Brazil) which corresponds to a value of 27.868809286999106 from the excel sheet that I reproduced above. Is there a built-in R function that would match the pairs from my df to extract its corresponding value? Thanks

Comment: You likely need a `merge` or join operation. You may find that many people on SO are somewhat averse to clicking on links, especially to download an excel file. Since your question has nothing to do with XLSX and mostly about data management, it would help immensely if you provided the output from `dput(head(dat))`, ensuring that that sample is both (1) small enough to not be gargantuan, avoiding too many unrelated columns, and (2) big enough to demonstrate the variability you need. For the second, ensure it has at least some matches in `countries`, and perhaps some countries that are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps what you need is `dplyr::pivot_longer`?

```
library(dplyr)

colnames(remittance)[1] <- 'source'

remittance %>% pivot_longer(-source, names_to = 'destination')


#----
# A tibble: 60 x 3
   source    destination    value             
   <chr>     <chr>          <chr>             
 1 Australia Brazil         27.868809286999106
 2 Australia Canada         46.827693406219382
 3 Australia Czech Republic 104.79905129342241
 4 Australia Finland        26.823089572300752
```

Note `remittance` is the dataframe in the OP `dput`.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way I would be able to remove the pairs that contain the same country? For example, I would like to remove (Australia, Australia) and (Brazil, Brazil) and so forth.

Comment: If you are ok using `dplyr` you can use `filter(source != destination)`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are interested in keeping the flexibility of your nice `combn` approach.

To loop over your *pairs* data frame (it's actually a matrix though) you may use `apply` with `MARGIN=1` for row-wise. In the `FUN=` argument we create data frames of one row each with *source* corresponding to column 1 of *pairs* and *destination* to column 2. The *dist*ance (or whatever this value is) we get by subsetting at the corresponding rows and columns of  *remittance* (for brevity I shortend to *rem*).

Since we will get a list of single-line data frames, we want to `rbind`, and because we have multiple objects we need `do.call`.

```
res <- do.call(rbind, 
               apply(pairs, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) 
                 data.frame(source=x[1], destination=x[2], 
                            dist=as.integer(rem[rem[, 1] == x[1], rem[1, ] == x[2]])))
)
```

Since the .xlsx has zeros where actually should be `NA`s we should declare them as such in the result.

```
res[res == 0] <- NA
```

#### Result

```
head(res, 25)
#       source        destination   dist
# 1  Australia             Brazil    721
# 2  Australia             Canada  24721
# 3  Australia     Czech Republic   1074
# 4  Australia            Germany  13938
# 5  Australia            Finland   1121
# 6  Australia     United Kingdom 135000
# 7  Australia              Italy  19350
# 8  Australia             Poland    974
# 9  Australia Russian Federation    543
# 10 Australia             Sweden   3988
# 11 Australia      United States  93179
# 12 Australia        Philippines   4118
# 13 Australia             France   8475
# 14 Australia        Netherlands  10697
# 15 Australia            Hungary    997
# 16 Australia       Saudi Arabia     NA
# 17 Australia           Thailand  11298
# 18 Australia        Korea, Rep.   5381
# 19 Australia          Indonesia  11094
# 20    Brazil             Canada  26647
# 21    Brazil     Czech Republic    742
# 22    Brazil            Germany  44000
# 23    Brazil            Finland   1378
# 24    Brazil     United Kingdom  55772
# 25    Brazil              Italy 104779
```

---

*Data:*

```
u <- "https://www.knomad.org/sites/default/files/2018-04/bilateralmigrationmatrix20170_Apr2018.xlsx"
rem <- openxlsx::read.xlsx(u)
countries <- c("Australia", "Brazil", "Canada", "Czech Republic", "Germany", 
              "Finland", "United Kingdom", "Italy", "Poland", "Russian Federation", 
              "Sweden", "United States", "Philippines", "France", "Netherlands", 
              "Hungary", "Saudi Arabia", "Thailand", "Korea, Rep.", "Indonesia")
pairs <- t(combn(countries, 2))
```